# Gem seems to affect other rails project of the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created a rails project *MyProject* and tried to set up [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) in it (using [this tutorial](http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/)). After I did some Devise stuff I could not scaffold `User` anymore, I ran into an error as shown below. So I wanted to start over, renamed the project to *MyProject-Devise* and created a new project *MyProject* to create `User` first and then do my Devise stuff. Now in my new project of the same name, when I run

```
rails generate scaffold user name:string email:string
```

I run into the same error. If I create a new app with another name, I can scaffold the user with the same command. So I guess it must be the same name thing.

Any ideas why this happens? How to get rid of the error or how to properly start the project over again?

This is the error:

> /Users/luke/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)

Full error here: http://pastebin.com/KFh4U6aS

Comment: Yes and I might even have run rake at some point and in the tutorial I had to run

Comment: Yes. And I might even have run rake and the tutorial also had me run ´rails generate devise:install rails generate devise user´

Comment: Not to sound crazy, there was a comment before asking if I used bundler

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not be using Bundler. The tutorial you linked to had you create a `Gemfile` but didn't tell you to run `bundle` or `bundle exec`. Without Bundler you may be using a Devise installed directly into your Ruby's gems.

I suspect if you run the `rails generate` command with `bundle exec` you may have different results.

`bundle exec rails generate scaffold user name:string email:string`

Comment: After I added the lines to the Gemfile I did run bundle install

Comment: Did you run the migration with `bundle exec`? That would be needed too (unless you've set up binstubs--which I'm happy to explain once we've got your issue resolved).